# UISearchbar filter after enter is pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I would like to know how can you prevent the UISearchbar from filtering an array of items after each character entry? and instead only do the one search after the search button or enter is pressed after the user has typed their search term.

I only ask as I have implemented a UISearchBar and unfortunately I have some really large data sets I am working with which really slow things down.

This is the UISearchBar I have created

```
filterSearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 170.0, 280.0, 40.0)];
        filterSearchBar.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeAllCharacters;
        UITextField *textField = [filterSearchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
        textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
        filterSearchBar.delegate = self;
        self.filterSearchBar.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeAllCharacters;
        if (([doorSearchString length] != 0) && (doorSearchString != nil)) {
            filterSearchBar.text = doorSearchString;
        }
        filterSearchBar.placeholder = @"Door filter";
        [allBackGroundView addSubview:filterSearchBar];
```

Comment: Use `- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar` delegate method of `UISearchBar` instead of `- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText`.

Comment: your not going to belive this.. I tried using it and thought it wasnt working... turned out I added it to the wrong class.. spent the last 45 minutes thinking I was going crazy! testing now will let you know how i go...

Comment: yep it worked perfectly. I will leave the quesiton here just incase someoneselse finds it usefull.

Comment: @Akhilrajtr I think you should post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `searchBarSearchButtonClicked:` delegate method of `UISearchBar` if you need to search only after pressing search button.

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    //Do search logic here
}
```

Don't forget set the `delegate` of `UISearchBar`. If you don't need to filter items after each character entry remove `- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText` delegate method.

Hope this helps